# Decimal digit problem

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

On Asp.Net, in my textbox, i do not want to enter after zero three numbers. 
For example if you enter textbox 0.222 it should be 0.22. After 0.22 you should not enter anything. How can i make this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent the user from _typing_ more than two digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Onsubmit, validate the content of the input. e.g. /\.\d\d$/.test(input.value)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Masked TextBox](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/item.aspx?i=387).

Comment: Yes.But after Point.For example if i enter 1.222 it should be 1.22 But you can enter 12345 Just I want to delete after point

Comment: Why would you do that? If you only want to have two digits after the decimal point, why would you allow the user to enter more? Why not restrict him to enter more than two digits in the first place?

Comment: it is related to math calculation. if you write 11111 ,calculation is ok.But 1.2222 is different.Our funciton does not accept.After point we do not want round, just deleting.

Comment: That's what a masked textbox is for. You can restrict it to two digits after the decimal point. If the user can only enter 1.22, it is exactly the same as if he enteres 1.22222 and you delete last three digits...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use an `Expression` instead of `Masked Textbox`.

With a simple `RegularExpressionValidator` you are able to do this, just drag one in your worksheet and then set the `TargetControl` of it to your Textbox, then set its value to `^\ddd`.

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't even loosely resemble his requirement... 0.22 would be invalid, 1dd would be valid...

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript add an attribute onkeyup='formatNumber(this)' on the tag.

```
function formatNumber(textBox) {

    var current = textBox.value;
    var output = "";

   //find '000' in current

   //delete what you want 

    textBox.value = output;
}
```